# Exact interpretation of inline-assembly code?

Tags: assembly, cpu, inline-assembly, cpu-registers, msr

I really wonder exact interpretation of inline assembly.
I basically know how inline assembly looks like :

```
__asm__ __volatile__(asms : output: input: clobber);
```

And below is an example :

```
void cpuGetMSR(uint32_t msr, uint32_t *lo, uint32_t *hi)
{
   asm volatile("rdmsr" : "=a"(*lo), "=d"(*hi) : "c"(msr));
}

void cpuSetMSR(uint32_t msr, uint32_t lo, uint32_t hi)
{
   asm volatile("wrmsr" : : "a"(lo), "d"(hi), "c"(msr));
}
```

Both don't have a 'clobber' part.

First, In cpuGetMSR, I think it means

```
"Read variable msr and store it %ecx, and write %eax value to *lo, and write %edx value to *hi"
```

Is it right interpretation? But where rdmsr goes? I need someone who can help me interprete cpuGetMSR() as well as cpuSetMsr(). Thanks

Comment: `rdmsr` "goes" between the input and the output of course. That's your assembler code. 1. set inputs 2. execute body 3. set outputs. PS: Please don't use image to post code.

Comment: @Jester you mean, "set %ecx as 'msr' --> execute rdmsr --> set *lo as %eax, and *hi as %edx" ??

Comment: really really appreciate :) .. Can I ask the extra question? Why are input and output needed when rdmsr, wrmsr executed? rdmsr just read the state of msr, and wrmsr is just write to msr. Are general purpose registers(eax,ebx,,etc) related with msr?. I read wiki and other materials like 10 times but i can't understand..

Comment: From Intel PRM:
WRMSR:Write the value in EDX:EAX to MSR specified by ECX.
RDMSR: Read MSR specified by ECX into EDX:EAX.
So yes, it is related

Comment: The inputs and outputs are needed because the compiler has no idea what your code does. It will just set up inputs as you tell it to, then insert the code, then expect results in the given locations. The compiler does not parse your code.

Comment: If you are trying to understand what goes where in an asm statement, there's nothing like the actual gcc docs to clear that up: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html  Probably more than you ever wanted to know.